# error "apc_fetch", pero con php-apcu instalado y funcionando

Tags: apache2, php7

Estoy instando en un servidor ubuntu 16.04 un sitio con apache/php7/mysql para una aplicacion symfony, la cual funciona actualmente en otro servidor.

Al intentar acceder en este nuevo servidor, el log me da:

```
[2017-04-26 11:45:16] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException: "Attempted to call function "apc_fetch" from namespace "Doctrine\Common\Cache"." at /var/www/mydomain/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/ApcCache.php
```

Revisando varios hilos de stackoverflow veo que suele ser un error de mal instalado apcu.

Al intentar un:

```
sudo apt-get install php-apcu
```

Apt me indica que ya esta instalado:

```
user@server:/# sudo apt-get install php-apcu
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php-apcu is already the newest version (5.1.3+4.0.10-1build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

y si preparo un archivo php con phpinfo(); me devuelve la tabla correspondiente y buscando apcu me encuentro con:

```
apcu

APCu Support            Enabled
Version                 5.1.3
APCu Debugging          Disabled
MMAP Support            Enabled
MMAP File Mask          no value
Serialization Support   php
Build Date              Apr 5 2016 02:16:47
```

tambien he revisado los paquetes php instalados. La lista la obtengo con dpkg -l |grep php:

```
blackfire-php             
dh-php                    
libapache2-mod-php        
libapache2-mod-php7.0     
newrelic-php5             
newrelic-php5-common      
php-apcu                  
php-cli-prompt            
php-common                
php-composer-semver       
php-composer-spdx-licenses
php-imagick               
php-json-schema           
php-pear                  
php-symfony-console       
php-symfony-filesystem    
php-symfony-finder        
php-symfony-process       
php7.0                    
php7.0-cli                
php7.0-common             
php7.0-curl               
php7.0-dev                
php7.0-fpm                
php7.0-intl               
php7.0-json               
php7.0-mbstring           
php7.0-mysql              
php7.0-opcache            
php7.0-readline           
php7.0-xml                
php7.0-zip                
pkg-php-tools
```

Estoy bastante confuso. Da la impresion de que esta instalado correctamente, pero la app indica que falla.

Alguna idea al respecto?

Comment: Parece ser que esa función está *deprecated*: [UndefinedFunctionException - Attempted to call function “apc_fetch” from namespace “Doctrine\Common\Cache”](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40038446)

Comment: No se me habia ocurrido mirar si estaba deprecated la funcion. voy a revisar a ver si consigo algo con esto. Gracias Trauma

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto. el problema estaba en que php-apcu no incluye la funcion apc_fetch (y otras necesarias de mi proyecto). La solucion ha sido instalar otro modulo llamado apcu_bc, con la linea

```
pecl install apcu_bc-beta
```

esto lo he encontrado aqui: https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-install-the-php-apcu-bc-extension.html

Gracias