# Attempted to call function "apc_fetch" from namespace "Doctrine\Common\Cache"

Tags: php, php5, symfony2

Uso Symfony 2 y PHP 5.6.29

Me sale el siguiente error

> Attempted to call function "apc_fetch" from namespace "Doctrine\Common\Cache".

Ya coloque en la carpeta C:\xampp\php\ext los archivos php_apc.dll php_apcu.dll

y el archivo php.ini esta asi

```
extension=php_apcu.dll
extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
;;extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll      ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll


; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed. 
; See http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php 
;extension=php_snmp.dll

;extension=php_soap.dll
;extension=php_sockets.dll
;extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;extension=php_xsl.dll

[apcu]
extension=php_apcu.dll
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_size=32M
apc.ttl=7200
apc.enable_cli=1
apc.serializer=php
```

Al ingresar a http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php no aparece el modulo instalado, no se que estoy haciendo mal

Comment: Hola Lina! Te sirve [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65556/error-apc-fetch-pero-con-php-apcu-instalado-y-funcionando)?

Comment: Para obtener la `DLL` de Windows tenes que [bajarla de acá](https://pecl.php.net/package/apcu_bc). Fijate en la tabla `Available Releases`, en columna `Downloads`, donde dice `DLL`. Si logras hacerlo funcionar, seria de mucha ayuda para todos que respondas a tu pregunta con los pasos que realizaste.